# JavaScript fade when window bottom passes a point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, fade

I have a div covered by another div, and I'm trying to get the cover to fade away (revealing the div beneath) once the bottom of the window is greater than halfway down the div. I was able to get it to work for fading once the top hit the top of the window, but i've edited it since then and it doesn't work anymore.

Here is a JSfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/DnJ2z/676/

and here is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var middleofDiv = $("#redCover").offset().top + (document.getElementById('redCover').clientHeight/2);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if(scrollBottom > middleofDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $("#redCover").fadeOut(2000); //reached the desired point -- show div
        }
    });
  });
```

For this example, I want it so that when the bottom of the window is more than halfway down the green div, the fade is triggered.

As a side note, I have three of these Div+coveredDiv on the page, all of class "background" and "cover". If I can get this Javascript to work, is there a way to make it work for all of the class instead of individual elements?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: You have invalid markup in your fiddle (wrong order of closing div tags), I've [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/DnJ2z/677/) it

Comment: your "updated" one doesn't seem right, sorry. It shows all 3 divs simultaneously.

Comment: Oh, my bad! I didn't understand the issue, nevermind that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `scrollTop()` is different depending on where you scroll to. You're running it `onload`, so it's always the same. It need to run in your `scroll` Event. Try this:

```
$(function(){
  var rC = $('#redCover'), middleofDiv = rC.offset().top + (rC.height()/2);
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > middleofDiv){
      //scrolled past the other div?
      rC.fadeOut(2000); //reached the desired point -- show div
    }
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnJ2z/684/)

As promised:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sT = $(window).scrollTop(), wH = $(window).height();
  $('.color').each(function(){
    var ths = $(this);
    if(sT + wH > ths.offset().top + (ths.height()/2)){
      ths.fadeOut(2000);
    };
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnJ2z/687/)

Note, that you do have `#greenDiv` around `#redCover`.

Comment: That worked, but I had to change ('redCover') to ("#redCover") with the double quotes and octothorpe. Why is that? What's the difference between the two in JavaScript?

Comment: Fixed. You are getting the `$(window).scrollTop()` when the page loads. Double quotes just require you to press the shift key (more work typing - You should also become a Dvorak Typist), so I use single quotes as much as possible. If I'm writing a bunch of HTML in JavaScript or PHP, I use double quotes on the outside with single quotes on the HTML attributes. There is only a speed difference in JavaScript, since the Server is not interpreting things in double quotes.

Comment: No, you have to use the `#` symbol to `document.getElementById()` in jQuery. jQuery uses CSS selectors.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! is there a way to make this work for any divs of a class or do I need to copy the code 3 times and change the IDs to get all three of the div combos where this happens?

Comment: Wait a minute. I'll add an example to Answer.